# matplotlib.pyplot fails to create box plot after creating a line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have code that creates a box plot, then a time series, then another box plot. I'm using python 3.7.3. Below is a distillation of the scenario. If I have code like this, reading from `datasheet.csv` (a `csv` file with first field as `Date` and the rest as `field1`, `field2`, etc):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

field1 = "field1"
field2 = "field2"
field3 = "field3"
field4 = "field4"
field5 = "field5"
datasheet_df = pd.read_csv("datasheet.csv")

# Make box plot 1
datasheet_df.boxplot([field1, field2], vert=False)
plt.savefig("boxplot1.png")

# Make box plot 2
datasheet_df.boxplot([field3, field4, field5], vert=False)
plt.savefig("boxplot2.png")

# Make time series
datasheet_df.plot(x='Date', y=[field1, field2])
plt.savefig("timeseries.png")
```

We correctly get the three figures:

[image: Figures when box plots are done first]

However, if I simply but the time series code before the box plot code, both the box plots are ruined. This is how my code actually is. The relevant code above subjected to this change would look like this:

```
...
# Make time series
datasheet_df.plot(x='Date', y=[field1, field2])
plt.savefig("timeseries.png")

# Make box plot 1
datasheet_df.boxplot([field1, field2], vert=False)
plt.savefig("boxplot1.png")

# Make box plot 2
datasheet_df.boxplot([field3, field4, field5], vert=False)
plt.savefig("boxplot2.png")
...
```

This results in these images:
[image: Figures when box plots are done second]

Why is this happening? Is there a way to get the box plots correctly displaying without changing the order that figures are being generated?

EDIT: I'd like some feedback on why I was downvoted; just tell me how I can improve rather than silently removing my edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you change default `x` axis value using `x='Date'`. When you use second and third of `datasheet_df.plot()` function, it automatically takes `x` in `Data` format for other plotting also. You can verify it by re-plotting `box plot 1` after `time series` in your first part of code

Comment: Thanks! This spurred me to find `matplotlib.pyplot.cla()`, a function that clears the axes, which simply needed to be placed after making the first plot. I was able to put this in to get the behaviour I wanted without changing the order that the plots were generated in.